# How to install PHP MySQL extensions

Tags: compiling, php, mysql, extension

I just installed a new server which comes with php 5.5. however one of my older projects requires php 5.3.

So I installed php 5.3 with

```
wget http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
tar -xvjf mirror
cd php-5.3.28
./configure --prefix /usr/local/php.5.3.28
make
make install
```

However php_mysql and php_pdo_mysql extensions are missing. So I was wondering how to install them into a custom php build on a server running with multiple php versions?

Server is running on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to see all ./configure options available run:

`configure --help`

to build an MySQL extension first install libmysqlclient-dev package and then add these options to `./configure` invocation:

`--with-mysql=/usr --with-pdo-mysql=/usr`

That should be it.

For shared .so extension do:

`--with-mysql=shared,/usr --with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr`

For mysqlnd (however I don't remember if 5.3 already had it)

`--with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd`

or

`--with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --enable-mysqlnd`